# use f-measure to evaluate the result from dbscan

Tags: scikit-learn, evaluate, dbscan

I'm using sklearn's interfaces to evaluate the result from dbscan, according to the document, F-measure is a classification metrics, but dbscan is a clustering method. I know F-measure can be used as a external evaluation method for clustering in theory. So how can I leverage it to evaluate the result from dbscan?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one f-measure, depending on how you define precision and recall. Because F is simply the geometric mean of precision and recall.

If you use ELKI, it will compute them automatically for you.

But the problem is the definition of precision and recall when the clustering algorithm produces noise (like DBSCAN does). Noise is not a cluster. But what is it then? How do you evaluate the quality of noise? How do you evaluate the clusters and the noise at the same time?

Many clustering evaluation measures fail to handle the case of noise, unfortunately. I am not aware of one measure that is really convincing wrt. noise treatment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I need to do my own realization based on F-measure, and what I should focus on is the noise processing, right?

Comment: The noise is a theoretical problem. There was some paper that discussed this (I believe by Campello?) - that would probably be the starting point. It seems far from easy.

Comment: If I remember correctly, ELKI implemented the different strategies discussed by Campello; so the reference to the article should be in the ELKI sources where they handle noise.